# Why SQL Server returns conversion error when mixing different data types in bulk INSERT statement?

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server, the version doesn't really matter, because it seems to work the same on most of the versions.

It's easier to show an example than explain:

```sql
CREATE TABLE form (
    id int primary key,
    response varchar(255) not null
);

INSERT INTO form (id, response)
VALUES (1, 1), (2, 'yes');
```

The 2nd statement fails with error `[S0001][245] Line 6: Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'yes' to data type int.`

How does this happen? Why is SQL Server trying to convert varchar to int when writing into varchar column? This makes no sense to me.

And can I make it not throw this error without explicitly converting int to varchar? I.e. make it accept exactly this input without modifying the input?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please , read this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/table-value-constructor-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver16#data-types) where is saying about the multiple rows INSERT data type.

> **Data Types** 
> The values specified in a multi-row INSERT statement follow the data type conversion properties of the UNION ALL syntax. This results in the implicit conversion of unmatched types to the type of higher precedence. If the conversion is not a supported implicit conversion, an error is returned. For example, the following statement inserts an integer value and a character value into a column of type char.

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.t (a INT, b CHAR);  
GO  
INSERT INTO dbo.t VALUES (1,'a'), (2, 1);  
GO
```

> When the INSERT statement is run, SQL
> Server tries to convert 'a' to an integer because the data type
> precedence indicates that an integer is of a higher type than a
> character. The conversion fails and an error is returned. You can
> avoid the error by explicitly converting values as appropriate. For
> example, the previous statement can be written as follows.

```
INSERT INTO dbo.t VALUES (1,'a'), (2, CONVERT(CHAR,1));
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, so it's the default behaviour and it's unavoidable. Gosh, SQL Server is a real mess. Other DBs handle this with no issues.

Comment: You can do this if you're looking for trouble

CREATE TABLE form (
    id int primary key,
    response sql_variant not null
);

INSERT INTO form (id, response)
VALUES (1, 1)
INSERT INTO form (id, response)
VALUES (2, 'yes');

Comment: @Stalinko I think most proficient developers would agree *stronger* data typing rules is a good thing. Helps prevent issues, such as inadvertent misaligned columns on insert etc. So quite the opposite of "*a real mess*". Also, each database system has minute differences around this too. Some handle it how you want, but not all do. The moral of the story is you should just write syntactically appropriate code. It also helps readability, as it's clear to someone reading the code that '1' is a string not integer based data type.

Comment: @J.D. actually that code is _syntactically_ correct. That's the problem. And yes I agree that strict data typing is good, but in some edge cases it makes things so difficult. I'm writing a data connector between JSON API and DBs. For MySQL it took me couple of hours, for MSSQL couple of days fighting with all limitations.

Comment: @Stalinko "*syntactically appropriate*" is what I said though. It causes a runtime error (which one could even argue that it's syntactically *incorrect* then, I just didn't go so far ;). I mean strict data typing is nothing new, and exists for good reason. I'm sure whatever actual issue you're facing has a more standardized solution though anyway. Best of luck!

Comment: I'm okay with strict data typing. But in my exact case I would expect another error that "int 1" can't be saved into varchar column. That would be absolutely clear and reasonable. But the background type casting from varchar to int when saving into varchar column is really confusing and looks like some caveat which had to be solved by developers but they were lazy.

Comment: @Stalinko "*But the background type casting...is really confusing...solved by developers but they were lazy*" - I mean there's a logical reasoning behind the rules, which are outlined in the docs. An order of precedence is defined between the native data types. Implicit conversion is allowed (and regularly happens) between them. But some of them are incompatible to convert because there's no logical mapping to do so. This is a benefit to T-SQL developers. But if you don't want to be explicit in the code you're writing, that's arguably being lazy lol. You should be able to handle this easily.

Comment: @Stalinko And let me provide you a scenario where your code may logically fail by not being explicit, even in database systems that allow a more lax syntax. Say your JSON object contains a BIT field of just 0s and 1s and instead of being explicit, you let the database figure it out, it may assume that data is an INT, and then store it inappropriately, wasting space. That's a very trivial example, but you can derive the point from it. There's much worse problems you can run into by not explicitly typing your JSON data before utilizing it in the database layer.

Comment: I'm not claiming at explicit type casting. It's a good thing. But when you're inserting a number and a string into a string field then the automatic casting of both values to number is the least what you expect. It means just something is wrong in the engine, but the developers decided to leave it as-is and let the users take care.

Comment: @Stalinko "*I'm not claiming at explicit type casting.*" - I know, I'm just saying the issue you ran into wouldn't occur if you were explicit in your code (which you should be if you want to write good code and avoid a multitude of potential issues) by using the syntax that indicates the value is a string in this case. "*It means just something is wrong in the engine*" - It's not something wrong in the engine because it lacks additional logic you'd want. That's just the same as me complaining that application languages have something wrong in their engine because they lack implicit conversion.

Comment: @Stalinko In other words, if SQL Server didn't do implicit conversion and just immediately errored, it would be akin to how application programming languages work at the expense of having even less logic / features in the engine, resulting in a worse user experience. But we don't blame application languages for lacking such a feature either. Implicit conversion is an additional feature that has its place and solves certain problems, but one needs to be aware of how it works too, and generally should be explicit in their code with fitting syntax and proper data types when applicable.